# I want to pass the data (UILabel) to a UILabel in another view controller without button

Tags: swift, segue

SwipeViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Label3: UILabel!

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let DestViewController : Daily = segue.destination as! Daily
    DestViewController.labeltext1 = Label1.text!
    DestViewController.labeltext2 = Label2.text!
    DestViewController.labeltext3 = Label3.text!
```

Then : Daily (DestinationViewController)

```
@IBOutlet weak var informationLabel: UILabel!

var labeltext1 = String()
var labeltext2 = String()
var labeltext3 = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    informationLabel.text = labeltext1
    informationLabel.text = labeltext2
    informationLabel.text = labeltext3

}//

func lineChartView(_ lineChartView: JBLineChartView!, didSelectLineAt lineIndex: UInt, horizontalIndex: UInt) {
    if (lineIndex == 0) {
        let Data = shakeData[Int(horizontalIndex)]
        let key_t = chartlegend[Int(horizontalIndex)]
        let label1 = String()
        informationLabel.text = "\(label1)\(key_t): \(Data)"


    } else if (lineIndex == 1) {
        let Data = swipeUpData[Int(horizontalIndex)]
        let key_t = chartlegend[Int(horizontalIndex)]
        informationLabel.text = "()\(key_t): \(Data)"

    } else if (lineIndex == 2) {
        let Data = swipeRightData[Int(horizontalIndex)]
        let key_t = chartlegend[Int(horizontalIndex)]
        informationLabel.text =  "()\(key_t): \(Data)"
    }
}
```

1. How can I pass the data (Label) from Swipe View Controller to Daily VC without button?
2. How to write the code in Daily VC if "informationLabel" is only one?

Help me Please!!!

Comment: What is your actual problem ? here as in your code how do you perform the segue, means what action is fired to go Destination View controller ?

Comment: How to write the label in each lineIndex with using only one informationLabel?